# Trying to create two columns from list of divs, extra white space in left column

Tags: html, css

I have series of divs that I am trying to render as two columns.  However, as you can see in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb32P/2/) there is extra spacing added in the left column above Group Heading 4 that I cannot seem to get rid of.  Is there any way to get rid of this extra space?  Must be IE8 compatible solution :-(  Thanks!

## HTML

```
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 1</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 2</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 3</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 4</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 5</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="INeedToColumn">
    <div class="groupheader">Group Heading 6</div>
    <div class="INeedToList">
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Test Link</a></div>
        <div class="INeedTo_ViewAll"><a href="#">View All</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.INeedToColumn {
      float:left;
      display:inline;
      width:45%;
      margin-right:30px;
      padding-bottom:8px;
      vertical-align:top;
      border-bottom:1px #B0BDC8 solid;
  }
.INeedToLink > div {
      float:left;
      display:inline;
      width:48%;
  }
  .INeedTo_ViewAll {
      width:100%;
      float:right;
      text-align:right;
  }
```

Comment: Linek is right, I didn't understand enough about how "float" works.  I ended up using the jquery columnizer library to get my columns to float appropriately and put the column breaks where I needed them.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nb32P/3/). Do you see how heading 3 is to the left now? You should try to understand `float` and the placement of divs a bit more.